# How to search in all text constants in Microsoft Dynamics NAV?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision

We're using Microsoft Dynamics NAV 2009 R2 6.00) and one of the users is running into an error. I'd like to locate the code throwing the error in order to be able to debug it. The errormessage itself is my best guess locating the code and I think it's either a text constant or just defined in code.

Is there a way to search in all text constants at once?

I've tried Object Manager -> Search String in C/AL code, but the text can't be located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer appears to be: All text constants are searched using `Object Manager -> Search String in C/AL code`.

As it turns out the text I was looking for isn't part of the C/AL code, but is found in an external .NET library, called from Navision.

Comment: Hm... Where is that Object Manager? This should be an add-on or third party solution? Do you have it out-of-the-box?

Comment: I think it's out-of-the-box, but I'm not 100% sure, because we do have some additional modules installed. The option can be found in the bottom left menu.

Comment: Object Manager typically refers to the add-on [Object Manager Advanced](http://www.idyn.nl/products/nav-development/object-manager-advanced).